# Passing the parameters based on the filename in shell script

Tags: shell, filenames

I have a requirement where I need to look for the new files in a particular location. Once I see a new file, I need to run other script which will move that file to a
different location. Now I want the first script to look for new files. Once I find any files, based on the filename, I need to trigger the second script by passing the corresponding keyword as parameters.

Suppose the filename is `abc_20.txt`. In my first script it has to look for `abc*.text`. Once I find such a file, I need to trigger the second script by passing the parameter as `abc`.
Second script command: `sh 2nd_script.sh abc`

Could you please help me how to compare the filename (`abc_20.txt`) with predefined keyword (`abc*.text`) and how to pass the corresponding keyword to the second script (`abc`)?

Comment: Makes little sense - `inotifywait` on the directory. But why two scripts, not one? Stackoverflow is a bad place to _learn_ programming, is a place for people that already _know_ programming to query about interesting programming problems.

Answer (score 0):

> how to compare the filename (abc_20.txt) with predefined keyword (abc*.text)

The term "keyword' is strangely used here - a *string* `abc*.text` is no keyword in shell, it has no special meaning.

The simplest and most portable way is to use `case`:

```
case "abc_20.txt" in
abc*.text) echo YES; ;;
*) echo NO; ;;
esac
```

> how to pass the corresponding keyword to the second script(abc)

As with any information passed to any script, the simplest would be to use positional parameters.

```
corresponding_keyword=something
second_script "$corresponding_keyword"
```

Answer (score 0):

If there may be 2nd_script.sh in the current directory,
you can execute 2nd_script.sh with the file matches "abc*.text" .

```
find . -name "abc*.text" -exec sh 2nd_script.sh '{}' \;
```